# Unmarshalling multiple XMLs with similar wrapper

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have multiple different XMLs with similar wrapper. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response id="085845">
  <class name="vera-pd" version="1.25" revision="1">
    <method name="platce-info">
      <status>0</status>
      <error_msg/>
      ... method content ...
    </method>
  </class>
</response>
```

I want to unmarshall them to POJOs based on the content or the attribute "name" in . Is something like that posible? I want to avoid having to write different ResponseClass for every method. XMLs arent mine, they come from different system so i am unable to use type or namespace.

I tried to use @XmlElements like this (classes MethodXX1 and MethodXX2 override VeraWSMethod). It didnt work because unmarshaller is unable to determine class and uses the last one in @XmlElements.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "class")
public class VeraWSClass {
    private String name;
    private String version;
    private String revision;
    private VeraWSMethod method;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "method", type = MethodXX1.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "method", type = MethodXX2.class)
    })
    public VeraWSMethod getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(VeraWSMethod method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to unmarshal XML instances that include varying content distinguished by a given attribute having different values.

Here is a standalone Maven demonstration [project](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/README.md) and [zip](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/releases/download/2.1.1/hisrc-basicjaxb-sample-platce-01-2.1.1-mvn-src.zip) that uses these JAXB features to provide a solution:

- `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MethodXmlAdapter.class)` - a JAXB annotation to specify a class to provide custom *unmarshaller* and *marshaller* methods.
- `MethodXmlAdapter.class` - receives a [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html) [`Element`](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) from JAXB when unmarshalling the *method* element. The `Element` instance is used to read the distinguishing name as a DOM attribute. When marshaling, JAXB provides a `MethodXXN` instance to be marshaled, in the adapter, to back to a DOM `Element` representation.

The key points for unmarshalling is the distinguishing attribute is programmatically accessible and the DOM element can be unmarshaled to the desired Java type.

[Context.mainUnmarshalByName(...)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/src/main/java/org/example/platce/Context.java)

```
public static Object mainUnmarshalByName(Element element)
{
    Object value = null;
    String name = element.getAttribute("name");
    switch (name)
    {
        case "platce-info":
            value = mainUnmarshal(element, METHODXX1_CLASS);
            break;
        case "platce-data":
            value = mainUnmarshal(element, METHODXX2_CLASS);
            break;
        default:
            value = element;
            break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The key point for marshalling is the different `MethodXXN` instances can be marshaled to the one *method* element using a declared [QName](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html) with or without a namespace.

[Context.mainWrapAsMethod(...)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/src/main/java/org/example/platce/Context.java)

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static Object mainWrapAsMethod(Object value)
{
    Object wrap = null;
    if ( value != null )
    {
        if ( isJAXBElement(value) )
            value = ((JAXBElement) value).getValue();

        if ( METHODXX1_CLASS.equals(value.getClass()) )
            wrap = new JAXBElement(METHOD_QNAME, METHODXX1_CLASS, value);
        else if ( METHODXX2_CLASS.equals(value.getClass()) )
            wrap = new JAXBElement(METHOD_QNAME, METHODXX2_CLASS, value);
    }
    return wrap;
}
```

##### Implementation

The [sample project](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/README.md) generates the JAXB classes using the [HiSrc HigherJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) Maven plugin and XJC plugins from [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme). The XML Schema defines the `MethodXXN` types as sub-types of `MethodBase` which contains common attributes and elements.

**Classes generated from [platce.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/src/main/resources/platce.xsd) by XJC**

```
org
└── example
    └── platce
        ├── MethodBase.java
        ├── MethodXX1.java
        ├── MethodXX2.java
        ├── ObjectFactory.java
        ├── Response.java
        └── VeraWSClass.java
```

The [platce.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/src/main/resources/platce.xsd) schema defines the `VeraWSClass` type to hold the *any* element; but, the [HiSrc HigherJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) Maven plugin uses the [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) customization XJC plugin and the [HiSrc HyperJAXB Annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) annotation XJC plugin to add the `@XmlAnyElement` and `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation using a separate configuration file: [VeraWSClass.any.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/platce-01/src/main/resources/org/example/platce/VeraWSClass.any.xml).

##### Execution

For the demo, you can run the test and/or application using:

```
mvn -Ptest clean test
mvn -Pexec compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/response01.xml"
mvn -Pexec compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/response02.xml"
```

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer for the forked [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme), [HiSrc HigherJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) and [HiSrc HyperJAXB Annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) projects.